# How to check user reputation from terminal?

Tags: support, reputation, api

Is there any way I can check a user's reputation or a specific question for updates using a terminal or command line?

Comment: You mean like running a `wget` command to fetch the number, or...? Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Which terminal?

Comment: Linux terminal , @animuson a quick way instead opening browser to check changes.

Comment: I believe there is a use-case for this, though I'd look at the API docs before asking.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't scrape it at a high frequency or your will be auto banned.

Comment: Yeah API sounds like the way to go for this

Comment: I'm not sure this needs a lot of downvotes. It's a fair question.

Comment: they think they are . but no problem. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was interesting enough to code up in python (3). (are big code dumps okay on meta?  Should I ask about that on meta-meta?)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

DISPLAY_FIELDS = OrderedDict([('display_name','name'),('reputation','rep'),('reputation_change_day','--today'),('reputation_change_week','--week'),('reputation_change_month','--month')])

def _format_url(id_):
    return 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/{}' \
    '?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow'.format(id_)

def main(id_,*args):
    r = requests.get(_format_url(id_))
    d = json.loads(r.text)
    print('StackOverflow info for id {}:'.format(id_))
    for k,v in DISPLAY_FIELDS.items():
        print('{:<8} {}'.format(v + ':',d['items'][0][k]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('id',type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.id)
```

Because I'm lazy (and because `urllib` is miserable) I used the external `requests` lib, fetchable at `apt-get install python3-requests`.

```
ben@nixbox:~$ ./sorep
usage: sorep [-h] id
sorep: error: the following arguments are required: id
ben@nixbox:~$ ./sorep 2581969
StackOverflow info for id 2581969:
name:    roippi
rep:     4402
--today: 45
--week:  500
--month: 1553
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the API documented here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me